# How to determine the highest dominant pole?

Tags: mosfet

[image]Attached is a circuit comprising two MOSFETs. I am asked to estimate the low midband frequency pole \$f_L\$. It is stated -- "the highest dominant pole determines \$f_L\$. Each pole frequency is just \$1/(2 \pi C_i R_{eqi})\$, where \$R_{eqi}\$ is the equivalent resistance \$C_i\$ "sees" between its terminals while \$C_j(j \neq i)\$ are short circuited. Simply check for the dominant pole (smallest multiplication of \$C_i\$ and the corresponding \$R_{eqi}\$)."
I think the smallest product would be for \$C_s\$, with \$R_{eqi}=2k\Omega\$, which yields \$f_L=79.577Hz\$. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a bit confusing because smaller value poles are more dominant. The smallest RC product would give the largest pole.

Comment: You are right that in this case the dominant pole is Cs and Reqi. But the pole Reqi is not equal to 2k Ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit is a MOS Cascode Amplifier
First of all, you should find which capacitors contribute to low frequencies.
To find this you should test individually for every capacitor if we replace it with open circuit, the gain reduced. If this is true then you understand that, this capacitor contribute to low frequencies.

The methodology that you refer above is correct.

fp1 = 1/{2*π*Cc1*Req1} = **588mHz**
Cc1 = 1uF
Req1 = 4k+ 800k//400k = 270.67K

fp2 = 1/{2*π*CS*Req2} = **374.53Hz**
Cs = 1uF
Req2 = (2k)// (1/gm1) = 2k // 540 Ω =  425.2 Ω
where gm1 = kn'(W/L) (VGS-VT) is the resistance when you looking the source of the M1(assuming λ=0 i.e ro infinity).
To find gm1 maybe you should analyze the circuit in DC and find that VG=4V,VS.Afrer calculation gm = 1.85mS and 1/gm = 540Ω, ID = 0.86mA

fp3 = 1/{2*π*CG*Req3} = **48.6mHz**
CG = 10uF
Req3 = 1800k//{(4k//800k)+400k} = 329.93k

fp4 = 1/{2*π*CC2*Req4} = **15.92Hz**
CC2 = 1uF
Req4 = 4k+6k= 10k
if λ<>0 then Req4 = 4k+ {6k//(ro2+ro1+(gm2+gmb2)*ro2*ro1) }= ...

As you can see when Req increases pole decreases.

> So the fL = fp2 = 374.53Hz

This online pdf I think will help you http://aries.ucsd.edu/NAJMABADI/CLASS/ECE102/12-F/NOTES/ECE102_F12-LecSet-8.pdf

Comment: Thanks G36.This is a very good observation and solves the problem for fp2

Comment: What extra date you are talking about ? Notice that we already know VG voltage VG = 4V. So from KVL we can write:$$V_G = V_{GS}+I_D*R_S$$  So additional if we assume $$I_D=Kn(V_{GS}-V_T)^2$$ and from there $$V_{GS}=V_G-I_D*R_S$$ we can solve for \$I_D\$ $$V_G=(V_G-I_D*R_S)+Kn((V_G-I_D*R_S) - V_T)^2 *R_S$$ $$I_D=1.125mA$$